# VBA to copy data from one sheet and paste against a range and repeat using LOOP or any other method

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially I tried doing using using Macro and see how it records in VBA. I have this dataset where I want to copy company names from a sheet and paste it next to years ranging from 1994-2014. And then repeat the same process for more roughly 800 companies.

I tried doing one with this code but I believe I need to loop the code. Not really a VBA expert just trying to saving time and error using VBA

```
Sub CopyPaste()
CopyPaste Macro
Sheets("Name").SelectRange("C3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Stata").Select
Range("B2:B22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

[image: Name Sheet]

[image: Output Sheet]

Comment: You could accomplish this using a cross join in Excel PowerQuery: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join. Then you could close and load to a new sheet. You'd want to set up your lists as Excel tables, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be very crude but the following code will accomplish what you want.  Especially if you only need to do this exercise once.

In my example the companies list starts in cell A2 and the output starts in cell D2.  I have used 3 years (2019 - 2021)

For the code below, the location (row & col) of the first company are placed in the variables copyRow & copyCol as integers (ie A2 = Row: 2, Col: 1)  The first cell of the output location is set in the pasteRow & pasteCol (ie D2 = Row: 2, Col: 4) variables.  Also the start year and end year are also set in the startYear and endYear variables.

Basically, from there it is just two nested loops.  A while for the companies that allows any number of companies as long as there are no empty cells in the list.  The for loop to cycle through each year between startYear and endYear for each company.

```
Sub copyPaste()

Dim copyWb As Workbook
Dim copySht As Worksheet
Dim pasteRow As Integer
Dim pasteCol As Integer
Dim copyRow As Integer
Dim copyCol As Integer
Dim startYear As Integer
Dim endYear As Integer

Set copyWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set copySht = copyWb.ActiveSheet
copySht.Activate

pasteRow = 2
pasteCol = 4
copyRow = 2
copyCol = 1
startYear = 2019
endYear = 2021

While copySht.Cells(copyRow, copyCol).Value <> ""
    
    For curYear = startYear To endYear
        copySht.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Value = curYear
        copySht.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol + 1).Value = copySht.Cells(copyRow, copyCol).Value
        pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
    Next curYear
    copyRow = copyRow + 1
    
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much and apprecaite your help ! Worked perfectly. However, I am trying to copy from one sheet and paste in another. Accordingly made some changes in code which has put below in the post. Would really appreciate your input on this

Comment: In the For loop you need to change the "copySht" on the left side of the "=" to "pasteSht" on both lines.  Leave copySht on the right side of the "=".  That should work.  If it still does work please submit the exact error you are seeing.  Also, I would suggest changing the initial values for pasteCol to 1 so that your data starts in Col "A" not "D"

Comment: FYI - The code assumes that "Sheet2" already exists.  You need to add the second sheet manually.  Just make sure that the name is correct in the Set statement.

Comment: Worked perfectly according to your instruction. Thank you so much you just saved tons of time for my master degree thesis!

Comment: I went on further to paste sales values corresponding to the years and company names from a source sheet and had (1) validation for both years and company names. However, when trying to see if the values retrieved from step 1 is same/true I ran into error. 

however, I have large dataset to do the same and would appreciate if you have any input in terms of VBA code do both step 1 and 2. Thank you again. 

Here is the thread link in superuser https://superuser.com/q/1692856/1313149

Comment: Sorry, I can't respond in SuperUser.  The only thing I see is that you are missing the reference to your sheet STATA! before the C2.  Although, I'm not sure why you are doing the check with the IFS statement.  You're basically taking the same formula you used to create the data and comparing it again.  It's not going to come up with a different result.  Personally, I wouldn't use the Index(Match,Match).  In your case you know that you only have one matching cell for both the company name and year.  In those cases I use a SUMIFS.  Much less confusing.  Good luck on your thesis.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make some changes to the code as I want to copy from one and paste in another sheet. I added the variable `pasteSht`, but when referencing to the `pasteSht.pasteRow` it's throwing me an error.

```
Sub copyPaste()

Dim copyWb As Workbook
Dim copySht As Worksheet
Dim pasteSht As Worksheet
Dim pasteRow As Integer
Dim pasteCol As Integer
Dim copyRow As Integer
Dim copyCol As Integer
Dim startYear As Integer
Dim endYear As Integer

Set copyWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set copySht = copyWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSht = copyWb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
copySht.Activate

pasteRow = 2
pasteCol = 4
copyRow = 2
copyCol = 1
startYear = 2019
endYear = 2021

While copySht.Cells(copyRow, copyCol).Value <> ""
    
    For curYear = startYear To endYear
        copySht.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Value = curYear
        copySht.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol + 1).Value = copySht.Cells(copyRow, copyCol).Value
        pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
    Next curYear
    copyRow = copyRow + 1
    
Wend

End Sub
```